# How to keep HTML indentation using DOMXPath?

Tags: php, html, indentation, domdocument, domxpath

I am using PHP (DOMDocument and DOMXPath classes to be more precise) to modify the content of an HTML file (for the moment I just change the title in the head tag and the first element of the body which is an h1).

The functionality is there meaning that I am able to modify what I desire into the document but the output is not keeping the indentation of the original file.

What solutions I found online are referring to XML, having to no effect when it comes to HTML.

My question is how can I keep my original indentation after using DOMXPath? It is even possible using this alone or I should consider some 3rd party library?

My PHP code snippet:

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile($dst . '/index.html');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$title_tag = $xpath->query('/html/head/title')->item(0);
$title_tag->nodeValue = $_POST['website-title'];
$body_tag = $xpath->query('/html/body/h1')->item(0);
$body_tag->nodeValue = $_POST['website-title'];
$dom->saveHTMLFile($dst . '/index.html');
?>
```

Original HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello world!</h1>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Output HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><meta charset="utf-8"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><title>Test Website</title><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"><link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico"><!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]--></head><body>
        <h1>Test Website</h1>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script></body></html>
```

EDIT: After using `$dom->formatOutput = true;` (thank you PeeHaa for this) before saving the HTML file, the output is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Test Website</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
        <h1>Test Website</h1>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$dom->formatOutput = true;`?

Comment: @PeeHaa Using `$dom->formatOutput = true;` before I save the HTML file is making the output way better, thank you very much. Unfortunately is not exactly the same as the original. It can be because of the automatic indentation Sublime Text is using?

Comment: ... does it really matter?

Comment: @CD001 Well, I hope that this will eventually become a tool which I can use for speeding up my process of creating Bootstrap websites and I prefer to use a code with indentation rather than a minified one.

Comment: ... but does it matter if it's the original indentation or the indentation created by `->formatOutput = true` ? Essentially, once you've imported the markup into DomDocument you've lost the original version.

Comment: @CD001 I thought that you are referring to the actual question. :D
Don't get me wrong, using `->formatOutput = true` is more than I've expected with such little effort. I am just curios if it can be exactly replicated otherwise what I have so far is excellent.

Comment: I think `formatOutput` is the best you can do - basically, DomDocument takes your original document and completely dismantles it to make something it can work with... it's an XML parser not a string manipulator.

Comment: @CD001 You should probably convert all above comments in a nice answer.